# Caught exception is None

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script written in python2.7 where I, for debugging purposes, use a catch-all statement to catch and print all exceptions. For some reason, the exception caught is sometimes `None`. What could cause this to happen?

the code is something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    run_arbitrary_code()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The output is then:

```
None
None
None
None
```

I have never experienced an exception being `None`, and wonder what could cause this.

To answer some of the comments, the function does quite a lot. It includes things like graph searches and sending and receiving JSON data over a socket, so there are quite a few things that could go wrong. But the issue here is that the raised exception is `None`, which does not help my debugging at all.

Comment: Not every `exception` is an actual error. I know that `sys.exit()` technically calls an exception and can, in fact, be caught. Can you identify the specific way you can make this happen? What happens with `print(str(e))`?

Comment: what does your function do?

Comment: Exceptions that aren't meant to be treated as errors do not subclass from Exception, so they won't be caught by this syntax.  SystemExit, GeneratorExit, KeyboardInterrupt directly subclass BaseException.

Comment: @Evan ah, my mistake. That will happen if you use `except:`; my brain must have substituted one for the other automatically.

Comment: For better debugging detail use `traceback.print_exc()` to print an exception and traceback.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look at the type of the exception, I bet it's a KeyError:

```
try:
    dict()[None]
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e), e)
```

Output:

```
<class 'KeyError'> None
```

Comment: the output is `"None"` :-)

Comment: @BartoszKP: However, if the `KeyError` is due to a `None` being specified as a key, it will output `None` when printed.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the issue. TIL: Allways print the type.

Comment: @Etse: that's why you should never catch a unknown exception. If you expect a KeyError, handle only the KeyError. Otherwise, let the exception fall through.

Answer (score 5):

You're better off printing the `repr` of the exception, not the default `str` that `print` applies, eg:

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    run_arbitrary_code()
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
```

Comment: It may be worth updating this with the sort of output produced for e.g. a KeyError.